# Avoid auto checked in other roles in role permission when i cheked the authenticate user role in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I have create a role "Unapproved".
Purpose of this role is to stop some authenticate user to access some specific page, But the problem is when i select authenticate user, then unapproved role also automatically checked and Un-editable, 
how can i checked and unchecked this role when authenticate user role activate?

sample of my problem
[image]

Comment: can you show a code example?

Comment: There is no code i have use, I have create roles by following this steps
people > permission > role